Error "Malformed IPv6 Address" with nodetool status in Cassandra 2.x Cluster
When I run nodetool status this error is thrown:
root@cassandra-cluster-01:/home# nodetool -h 192.168.2.228 status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '192.168.2.228:7199' - URISyntaxException: 'Malformed IPv6 address at index 7: rmi://[192.168.2.228]:7199'.
root@cassandra-cluster-01:/home# nodetool status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - URISyntaxException: 'Malformed IPv6 address at index 7: rmi://[127.0.0.1]:7199'.

The way the Cassandra 2.x was installed (What could be wrong with this?):
#!/bin/bash

# Define variables
CASSANDRA_VERSION="2.2.19"   # Specific 2.x version to install
NODE_IP="192.168.2.228"      # IP address for the current VM and seed node

# Update package lists and install prerequisites
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y wget gnupg2 lsb-release

# Install Zulu JDK 8
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys B1998361219BD9C9
echo "deb http://repos.azulsystems.com/debian stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/zulu.list
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y zulu-8

# Verify Java installation
java -version

# Download and install Cassandra
wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/cassandra/$CASSANDRA_VERSION/apache-cassandra-$CASSANDRA_VERSION-bin.tar.gz
tar -xvf apache-cassandra-$CASSANDRA_VERSION-bin.tar.gz
mv apache-cassandra-$CASSANDRA_VERSION /opt/cassandra

# Create symbolic links
ln -s /opt/cassandra/bin/* /usr/local/bin/

# Download jamm-0.3.0.jar and place it in the lib directory
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/stephenc/jamm/0.3.0/jamm-0.3.0.jar -P /opt/cassandra/lib/

# Set up environment variables for Cassandra
cat <<EOF > /etc/profile.d/cassandra.sh
export CASSANDRA_HOME=/opt/cassandra
export PATH=\$PATH:\$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin
EOF
source /etc/profile.d/cassandra.sh

# Ensure permissions are set correctly
chmod -R 755 /opt/cassandra

# Update JVM options to include the jamm agent
cat <<EOF >> /opt/cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.sh
JVM_OPTS="\$JVM_OPTS -javaagent:\$CASSANDRA_HOME/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar"
EOF

# Create Cassandra service
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/cassandra.service
[Unit]
Description=Apache Cassandra
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra -f
ExecStop=/bin/kill -9 \$(cat /opt/cassandra/cassandra.pid)
User=root
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

# Reload systemd to recognize the new service
systemctl daemon-reload

# Stop Cassandra to configure
systemctl stop cassandra

# Configure Cassandra
sed -i "s/^# broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4/broadcast_rpc_address: $NODE_IP/" /opt/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
sed -i "s/^listen_address: localhost/listen_address: $NODE_IP/" /opt/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
sed -i "s/^rpc_address: localhost/rpc_address: $NODE_IP/" /opt/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
sed -i "s/^- seeds: \"127.0.0.1\"/- seeds: \"$NODE_IP\"/" /opt/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml

# Enable auto_bootstrap
echo "auto_bootstrap: true" | tee -a /opt/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml

# Start Cassandra service
systemctl start cassandra

# Enable Cassandra to start on boot
systemctl enable cassandra

# Verify Cassandra installation
nodetool status

# Provide information about the installation
echo "Cassandra installation and initial configuration completed. Please check the nodetool status above for cluster status."


I have previously documented this issue on DBA StackExchange. Below is a quick summary.
Newer versions of Java 8 changed the way it parsed the URL for JNDI providers (JDK-8278972). This URL in Cassandra 2.2 NodeProbe.java class (used by nodetool) is no longer accepted by the RMI URL parser:
    private static final String fmtUrl = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://[%s]:%d/jmxrmi";

The issue was fixed in Cassandra 3.x and newer releases (CASSANDRA-17851). Cassandra 2.2 has reached end-of-life in 2021 so it is no longer supported and will not get patched.
You can workaround the problem by either (a) using the legacy URL parser (with the JVM flag -Dcom.sun.jndi.rmiURLParsing=legacy), or (b) explicitly adding an IPv6 subnet prefix when specifying the hostname (with -h ::FFFF:127.0.0.1). For details, see my original post on StackExchange linked above. Cheers!
